# Google Maps Overlay seems to be transparent

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add an overlay for different counties in Oregon to google maps.

I have all the latlng data for a county in a json file that I am pulling in with jquery. The problem I'm getting is that the overlay seems to be there but it's transparent.

Including some pictures to show why I'm pretty sure that the overlay is there

This is the cursor when the mouse isn't over Baker County:

[image]

This is the cursor when the mouse is over Baker County:
[image]

So now I'm wondering what might be causing this in my code.

```
function initialize() {
    var oregon = new google.maps.LatLng(43.804, -120.554);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: oregon,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    countryPolygons = null;

    $.getJSON("json/counties.json", function(data){
        county_data = data;

        county_latlng = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < county_data.data.length; i++) {
            var county = county_data.data[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < county.latlng.length; j++) {
                var latlng = county.latlng[j];

                var first = parseFloat(latlng.split(",")[0]);
                var second = parseFloat(latlng.split(",")[1]);

                county_latlng.push(new google.maps.LatLng(first, second));
            }
        }

        countyPolygons = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: county_latlng,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        countyPolygons.setMap(map);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The counties.json file looks something like this, shortened obviously.

```
{
    "title": "Counties",
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "Baker",
            "latlng": [
                "44.65488,-118.42475",
                "44.64548,-118.38275",
                "44.62488,-118.34425",
                "44.56938,-118.31765",
                "44.53442,-118.36868",
                "44.47498,-118.36365",
                "44.45698,-118.39215",
                "44.44968,-118.42197",
                "44.41998,-118.42445",
                "44.39781,-118.43485",
                "44.38148,-118.41425",
                "44.35345,-118.43539",
                "44.28621,-118.49621",
                "44.25719,-118.24407",
                "44.25608,-118.23214",
                "44.25608,-118.23002",
                "44.27077,-118.18471",
                "44.29948,-118.14044",
                "44.31403,-118.12604",
                "44.34918,-118.08677",
                "44.37726,-118.05169",
                "44.40939,-118.03151"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't see anything that would make the overlay transparent.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What does your counties.json look like?

Comment: If I put the JSON in the format that your code expects it [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_transparentPolygons1.html).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that one of the other developers stuck in a `canvas { display: none; }` in the css and that's what caused the problem.